# How to change form action url based on selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, onchange

I'm trying to build a search box were students can search for course reserves based on their course code or faculty members names. What is missing is the part where you can change the form action url based on the checkbox you mark. I took the javascript code from the previous search box where it was used on a dropdown selection. I knew it wouldn't work on input but that's where my javascript understanding ends. Btw, I have a javascript running which allows only one checkbox to be selected. My code goes like:

```
<form name="frm" method="get" action="http://path1" />
    <input name="SEARCH" value="" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
    <input type="submit" value="" />
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" value="http://path1" checked="checked"/>
      <label for="course">Course Code</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" value="http://path2"/>
      <label for="faculty">Faculty Member</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
var objForm = document.search;
if (objForm.type.checked)
    {
    objForm.removeChild(objForm.searchType);
    objForm.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is javascript?

Comment: Sorry, added the javascript. I also tried **onchange="document.frm.action = this.options[this.selectedValue].value;"** but didn't work. Perhalps it could be solved with onchange too.

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: No, for now it's plain html and a bit javascript. But I'm open to all kind of suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have only two option I have made it radio but still if you want checkbox then change it:

```
<form name="frm" id="myForm" method="get" action="http://path1" >
    <input name="SEARCH" value="" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
    <input type="submit" value="" />
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="frmact" value="http://path1" checked="checked" onclick="formaction(this)"/>
      <label for="course">Course Code</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="frmact" value="http://path2" onclick="formaction(this)"/>
      <label for="faculty">Faculty Member</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
</body>
<script>
function formaction(checkbox){
    document.getElementById("myForm").action = checkbox.value;;
}

</script>
```