# Change an url on an image depending on something checked before

Tags: javascript, wordpress, image, hyperlink, href

I am trying to make an E-commerce website. I'm using Wordpress/Woocomerce.
But the guy I am working for, wanted special pages with a really special design. So he asked me for something that I did.
But now the fact is that I have a problem with the attributes and adding it to the cart button.

So I'd like to find a way to change the url on the "add to cart" button, which is an image.
Is there anyway to make an url on a page ( not in the search bar, but in the code ) change if u `check` or `uncheck` something ?
Like a `radio` button or anything.

Also I'm looking for a cool way to keep the selected size white once I clicked on. Actually it's just an image with an `invert effect` on `hover` . And I just *found a way* to make all work with 1 page per size but it would be really could if I could change the link on the <kbd>add to cart</kbd> button change. I just dont know how to change it.

Here is the link : http://mtcdistrup.cluster003.ovh.net/black-onyx/

As you can see, if u click on **S** it loads another page and on the new page the <kbd>add to cart</kbd> button links straight to the good product.

I hope all is clear and that u can help me a bit.

Comment: Is there a hyperlink around the button? An <a href=""></a> tag? If so, edit the url inside the href, else try finding the click event of the button and see if it contains an url.

Comment: @Nemzytch, Kindly Go through [How to change URL based on Selected Checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311850/how-to-change-form-action-url-based-on-selected-checkbox)